# Automated emails for late registrants

Tags: civievent, civimail

We send out the information regarding the event 2 weeks prior; however, folks can sign up until the night before the course. Is there a way to create an automated email that only goes out to registrants who sign up after that email goes out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do that with the standard event mails nor with scheduled reminders? Or perhaps you can do this with the scheduled reminders when you add all those folks to a special (temporary) group?

Alternatively you might want to try the CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) although I think your request would require some additional conditions.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had the feeling about. It may be easiest to just add the text to the receipt text after they send it out to everyone.

Comment: Are we sure that late registrants won't simply get the reminder on the next cron run?  IIRC Scheduled Reminders looks for all participants that fit the criteria, then filters out anyone who has received that reminder already (via querying `civicrm_action_log`).  Assuming the reminder date is relative, not fixed, it should check on every cron run who hasn't received the message and send it (up until the *Effective End Date*).  So my guess is that if the original info was sent via Scheduled Reminder, the late registrants would also get the reminder.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain they're doing the original as a scheduled reminder. So if they create the 2 week email as a scheduled reminder, it should send the same to folks who register after that?

Comment: Late answer - but yes, a Scheduled Reminder set to go out 2 weeks before an event will go out to anyone who registers within the 2 week period who hasn't received the email.  Note that this can backfire on you - you might make a membership renewal email that goes out to people who lapsed years ago!  The "Effective Start Date" field on modern Civi's Scheduled Reminders field is meant to avoid running reminders on very old events/memberships/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the extension "[Custom Event Communication](https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/)" and create a rule for an email there. However you would still need to create the rule manually two weeks before the start date.